# Win7 Guest account and WiFi\Wireless network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, guest-account

When I login using Win7's Guest account, the WiFi symbol (5 bars) in the system tray is gone and I have no way to control the WiFi connectivity. For already defined connections, the computer connects, but I can't connect to new ones.

How come and is there a way to change this, assuming I also have access to a privileged user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, here it goes the answer to connect to wireless networks as a guest user.  The answer is in the Control Panel but **NOT** in managing user accounts - the only two things you can manage for the guest user account are to disable it or to change its image, anyway.  Rather, at the Control Panel you must go to Network Center and then to manage wireless networks, where you have to do two things:

- As an administrator user: Click on `profile types` and make sure to choose the option that includes profiles per user.  Once this is done, the guest user can add wireless connections at any time.  You can do this as an administrator user or a guest user, but in the last case you are prompted for a password to an administrative user.
- As guest user: Click `Add` to add new wireless connections.  You can now add limitless wireless connections, but... only manually.  There's no way to get the usual list of detected wireless networks, as far as I know.  This means you need to input the name of the network (SSID), input the security type at a pull-down menu (i.e. WPA2-Personal), choose the cypher type at another pull-down menu (i. e. AES) and finally input the password.  This might take some patience - if you only know the SSID and the password, you have to try with different values from security type and cypher type, and there are eleven possible combinations.

Comment: It Works!! You saved me

Answer (score 2):

> How come and is there a way to change this, assuming I also have
>   access to a privileged user?

Adjust the priviliages of this account using the user control interface and policy panel.

Answer (score 0):

The windows Guest account is super restricted and I doubt you get much control over it in W7 Home editions.

Probably easier just to create a new user without a password, or a weak password that you don't mind sharing with people who use your computer.

(Assuming this is home use... would be silly to use Guest accounts in any business environment)